# WPF Resources not loading?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Alright, so I've got a bit of XAML that doesn't seem to want to work. It's meant show the value of "MainWindowViewModel.Property" but it doesn't do that.

First, the code:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="{Binding Property, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public string Property = "test";
    }
}
```

This seems pretty correct to me but it doesn't work in runtime and the designer gives me a cryptic error:

```
PropertyPath
 Property expected
```

Around the "`Property`" in the Binding. Any ideas why this could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the `Property` member of your `MainWindowViewModel` is a [*field*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) and not a [*property*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx), and WPF only supports binding to properties. So your view model should look at least something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Property = "test";
        }

        public string Property { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If you're planning on changing the value through the course of the life of your view model you might also consider implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I didn't notice that. Actually this will probably do the trick for OP!

Comment: OH! That's pretty weird... Is it a technical limitation or just the way it was designed?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. I do not know for sure, but I think it was a design choice rather than a technical limitation - if you follow "the fields link" in the answer you'll find a comment in one of the code snippets stating that public exposition of fields is "generally not recommended" and it's best practice to do it by means of properties.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I believe you should do:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

and bind as:

```
    <Label Content="{Binding Property}"/>
```

Also take note of your namespaces:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
```

but your viewmodel seems to be somewhere else

Comment: That was an error in copying, mainly. Will try this when I get off mobile though!

Comment: @It'sNotALie.I figured it was just an error. It should do it

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

In your ViewModel make a Property by name *Property* like:

```
private string _property;
public string Property
{
    get{ return _property;}
    set{ _property = value;}
}


public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    Property = "test";
}
```